# Asus Rog GL702ZC shuts down on GPU memory clock stress

Tags: gpu, shutdown, asus-laptop, laptop-repair, clockspeed

My laptop has the following specifications:

RX 580

Ryzen 1600

8GB RAM

SSD + HDD

A week ago I gave my laptop to a local service to have it cleaned up and some new thermal paste applied due to higher temperatures that I noticed. After I got it back every time I run anything GPU related, the laptop shuts down in an instant.

I have narrowed it down to the following. If my laptop is in "better/best performance" power mode, any GPU stress test/game will shut it down in 1 second. If the laptop is in "better/best battery saving" power mode, the laptop will be able to play games and run benchmarks, although at low FPS.

Only thing I know that the laptop does differently in those modes is the GPU memory clock. If the GPU memory clock gets boosted to 2000MHz(default, no overclock od any component) from idle 300MHz, a crash occurs. GPU mem clock is kept at 300MHz in battery saving modes even in stress tests(core clock goes to 1077), while the high performance boosts it to 2000MHz on any stress. This is the repaste job.

[image]

GPU idle temps: 60-70

CPU idle: 50-55

Under full load, I cant get a GPU reading, so no temps here but CPU goes to 80 on CPU only benchmarks.
Yeah. Only when GPU is stressed to boost mem clock to 2000MHz, every other bench is runnable and tests all show pass on SSD, RAM, HDD.

It doesn't restart on shutdown nor does it show any event errors. It did show bugcheck 0x0000116 and 0x0000154, but only once since this has been occurring.

Comment: Sounds like you should take it back to the local service. Since there is a direct correlation to their work and your problems.

Comment: I'm on my holidays, so no service until the 26th of August. This is a mistery I can't explain

Comment: Seems obvious to me, whatever work you had done, is the cause of your problems.

Comment: Well the work was: clean out the fans from dust and put a new thermal paste. I know it's obvious. But how does that lead to this, that is the mistery I'm trying to solve

Comment: If your GPU is idle at 60-70 that is pretty darn hot actually.

Comment: I know. My guess is the thermal pads on the VRMs are faulty in some way which causes instant shutdown when power is needed or the paste is not properly applied (non conductive) and thus causing overheat because the controller can "see" that the heat dissipation is bad and to protect it, it shuts down...or the heatsink does not sit well with the paste. I doubt the power adapter is faulty or the battery, because I've tested on all 3 combinations (bat, bat+ada, ada only). Same thing, gpu mem clock to 2000, laptop shutdown